# How to move files based on file names in a.csv doc - macOS Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Terminal noob need a little help :)

1. I have a 98 row long filename list in a .csv file. For example:
   name01; name03, etc.
2. I have an external hard drive with a lot of files in chaotic file
   structure. BUT the file names are consistent, something like:
   name01_xy; name01_zq; name02_xyz etc.
3. I would like to copy every file and directory from the external hard
   drive which begins with the filename stored in the .csv file to my
   computer.

So basically it's a search and copy based on a text file from an eHDD to my computer. I guess the easiest way to do is a Terminal command. Do you have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot depends on the structure of your `.csv` file - what is the delimiter? How many columns do you have? Are header lines present? Update your question with a snippet from the file, five first rows would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is the first 5 row, something like this goes to 98 row. I have one only column without header:
bea001f001
bea003n001
bea007f005
bea008f006
bea009n003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task can be split into three: read search criteria from file; find files by criteria; copy found files. We discuss each one separately and  combine them in a one-liner step-by-step:

#### Read search criteria from `.csv` file

Since your `.csv` file is pretty much just a text file with one criterion per line, it's pretty easy: just `cat` the file.

```
$ cat file.csv
bea001f001
bea003n001
bea007f005
bea008f006
bea009n003
```

#### Find files

We will use `find`. Example: you have a directory `/Users/me/where/to/search` and want to find all files in there whose names start with `bea001f001`:

```
$ find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "bea001f001*"
```

If you want to find all files that end with `bea001f001`, move the star wildcard (zero-or-more) to the beginning of the search criterion:

```
$ find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "*bea001f001"
```

Now you can already guess what the search criterion for all files *containing* the name `bea001f001` would look like: `"*bea001f001*"`.

We use `-type f` to tell `find` that we are interested only in finding files and not directories.

#### Combine reading and finding

We use `xargs` for passing the file contents to `find` a `-name` argument:

```
$ cat file.csv | xargs -I [] find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "[]*"
/Users/me/where/to/search/bea001f001_xy
/Users/me/where/to/search/bea001f001_xyz
/Users/me/where/to/search/bea009n003_zq
```

#### Copy files

We use `cp`. It is pretty straightforward: `cp file target` will copy `file` to directory `target` (if it is a directory, or replace file named `target`).

#### Complete one-liner

We pass results from `find` to `cp` not by piping, but by using the `-exec` argument passed to `find`:

```
$ cat file.csv | xargs -I [] find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "[]*"  -exec cp {} /Users/me/where/to/copy \;
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: for some reason search only happens with the last name in the csv file

Comment: same as @SamAxe. it searches only with the last name in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is my first post here.  In response to the comments above, only the last file is selected likely because the others have a carriage return `\r`.  If you first append the directory to each filename in the csv, you can perform the move with the following command, which strips the `\r`.

```
cp `tr -d '\r' < file.csv` /your/target/directory
```